# Java classpath fails but eclipse works

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run code that uses a sql driver for jbdc it works on eclipse. This is after I went into the project properties and added the external jar. However when I run the following from the command line it fails.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
javac sql_stuff.java 
java sql_stuff -classpath conn.jar

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://...
```

Same with -cp

```
 javac sql_stuff.java 
 java  sql_stuff -cp conn.jar
```

In Eclipse all I had to do is go project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and add the jar file.

Edit

Got it finally running with

```
java -cp .:conn.jar sqlstuff
```

Java seems to need to 're-add' a class path (even though it was '.' !!!) otherwise it wouldn't find the class. Also you have to use : as a separator (or sometimes ; ), god knows why. Hopefully this will help others when they stumble across issues.

Comment: You need to give the `-cp` on the `java` command, not the `javac` command. The driver is not needed during compilation, but it **is** needed at run-time.

Comment: @Andreas I updated the code, still same problem.

Comment: Put the `-cp` and its argument *before* the class name. By the way, class names should not have underscores, and should start with a capital letter, like `SqlStuff`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic that was it! I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the `java` command, all the "switches" (things starting with -) that come *before* the class name are considered arguments to the JVM. All those that come *after* the class name are considered arguments to the `main` method in the class.

So the command line:

```
java ClassName -cp conn.jar
```

Will be interpreted as "run with no JVM arguments, passing the array `{ "-cp", "conn.jar" }` as `args` to `main`.

While the command line:

```
java -cp conn.jar ClassName
```

Will be interpreted as "run with a classpath of `conn.jar`, and call `main` in `ClassName` with an empty `args` array".

So always remember to pass all JVM arguments, including the classpath, **before** the name of the class.

Comment: I had to also pass '.' to the class path as well. Otherwise the class wouldn't be found. Thanks for the help and the detailed run down.